# Why lm command doesn't show a module?

Tags: debugging, kernel, virtual-machine, windbg

I opened a calculator in the virtual machine but when try to view it from windbg using the command `lm` doesn't show up.

```
kd> !process 0 0 calc.exe
PROCESS ffffe0000046a080
    SessionId: 1  Cid: 0144    Peb: 7ff7f76df000  ParentCid: 0868
    DirBase: 18290000  ObjectTable: ffffc000031739c0  HandleCount: <Data Not Accessible>
    Image: calc.exe

kd> .process ffffe0000046a080
Implicit process is now ffffe000`0046a080
kd> !peb
PEB at 00007ff7f76df000
    InheritedAddressSpace:    No
    ReadImageFileExecOptions: No
    BeingDebugged:            No
    ImageBaseAddress:         00007ff7f8060000
    Ldr                       00007ffdc286f3c0
    Ldr.Initialized:          Yes
    Ldr.InInitializationOrderModuleList: 0000008db0261ae0 . 0000008db028fb60
    Ldr.InLoadOrderModuleList:           0000008db0261c40 . 0000008db028fb40
    Ldr.InMemoryOrderModuleList:         0000008db0261c50 . 0000008db028fb50
                    Base TimeStamp                     Module
            7ff7f8060000 5215ed3e Aug 22 05:51:42 2013 C:\Windows\system32\calc.exe
            7ffdc2740000 523d5305 Sep 21 03:04:21 2013 C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
            7ffdc03e0000 523d5199 Sep 21 02:58:17 2013 C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
            7ffdbfec0000 523d557d Sep 21 03:14:53 2013 C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
```

Changing the context doesn't help but i had to try it. I remember listing *calc* at the top of the list, but i don't know under what circumstances

```
kd> lm
start             end                 module name
fffff800`00000000 fffff800`00088000   CI         (deferred)             
fffff800`0008a000 fffff800`000f0000   mcupdate_GenuineIntel   (deferred)             
fffff800`000f0000 fffff800`000fe000   werkernel   (deferred)             
...
```

Comment: Does `lm m calc` show it? It needn't be at the top of the list.

Comment: @ThomasWeller no, maybe because calc.exe is a user application, i'm not windbg expert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either use .process /p /r

or use
.reload /user

for your user mode modules to be listed

```
kd> !process 0 0 calc.exe
PROCESS 865a3030  SessionId: 1  Cid: 0fe4    Peb: 7ffda000  ParentCid: 0850
    DirBase: 7e24a6e0  ObjectTable: c44a2df0  HandleCount:  81.
    Image: calc.exe

kd> .process 865a3030
Implicit process is now 865a3030
kd> lm m calc*
Browse full module list
start    end        module name

kd> .reload /user
Loading User Symbols

kd> lm m calc*
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
00e00000 00ec0000   calc       (deferred)
```

or

```
kd> !process 0 0 calc.exe
PROCESS 865a3030  SessionId: 1  Cid: 0fe4    Peb: 7ffda000  ParentCid: 0850
    DirBase: 7e24a6e0  ObjectTable: c44a2df0  HandleCount:  81.
    Image: calc.exe

kd> .process 865a3030
Implicit process is now 865a3030
kd> lm m calc*
Browse full module list
start    end        module name


kd> .process /p /r 865a3030
Implicit process is now 865a3030
Loading User Symbols

kd> lm m calc*
Browse full module list
start    end        module name
00e00000 00ec0000   calc       (deferred)
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing as blabb said, it does shows it, in fact lists not only kernel memory(fffff8...) but user memory(00007..) as well.

```
kd> lm
start             end                 module name
00007ff7`35260000 00007ff7`35346000   calc       (deferred)             
00007ffa`f7500000 00007ffa`f7563000   oleacc     (deferred)             
[...]       
00007ffa`fcbe0000 00007ffa`fcd89000   ntdll      (deferred)             
fffff800`00000000 fffff800`0005f000   volmgrx    (deferred)             
[...]     
fffff800`000dd000 fffff800`0013f000   CLFS       (deferred)
```

Comment: But makes me think that the explanation behind is about the context where you load the symbols, anyone correct me if i'm wrong